# How to map the attribute and variations to get the variation id from woocommerce rest API

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am developing an application using WooCommerce rest API v3. Now I need to display the variable product with its attributes and variations. From the product endpoint, I got the product details along with its attributes, variations & options id. how to get the variation id from the above details. Is there any specific endpoint available to get the variation id. or how to
map the attributes and variation with option id?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please include your code too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.